# Delimited file parser

Tags: c#, parsing, file

This is some code I've cobbled together that reads a delimited file. If the user is able to tell us some stuff about the file, it uses the supplied information. Otherwise, it tries to work stuff out itself. Then it pushes what it thinks are the first two rows of data back to the user to see if it's read the file correctly.

The problem I've faced is that efficiency is important, so I've tried to only read the file once. That creates a chicken and egg problem if the user hasn't given us a delimiter - we need to read the first row to determine the delimiter, but we can't get the fields in the first row without knowing what that delimiter is.

What I've written works but it's an awful mess in terms of readability. I've added comments for this SE question to help explain some decisions. Can you help me make the code clearer and cleaner while still keeping it as quick as possible?

```
[RequireHttps]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private IFileParser _fileParser;

    public HomeController(IFileParser fileParser)
    {
        _fileParsers = fileParser; // this is handled via Ninject
    }

    // other ActionResults

    public ActionResult NewJob(Job job)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // FileQueue is a DTO - you can ignore this constructor
                FileQueue fQ = new FileQueue(file); 
                string[] firstline = null, secondline = null;

                if (Request["AutoDetect"] == null)
                {
                    // these will either all be blank or all populated
                    fQ.FieldDelimiter = Request["FieldDelimiter"];
                    fQ.TextDelimiter = Request["TextDelimiter"];
                }

                _fileParser.ParseFirstTwoRows(fQ, ref firstline, ref secondline);

                if (fQ.TextDelimiter == "")
                {
                    if (_fileParser.IsFileDoubleQuoteDelimited(firstline) || _fileParser.IsFileDoubleQuoteDelimited(secondline))
                    {
                        fQ.TextDelimiter = "\"";
                    }
                }

                fQ.NumberOfFields = firstline.Count();
                fQ.FirstLine = firstline;
                fQ.SecondLine = secondline;

                return RedirectToAction("FieldMapping", fQ);
            }
        }

        return View("Error");
    }
}

public class FileParser : IFileParser
{
    // other file parsing functions

    public void ParseFirstTwoRows(FileQueue file, ref string[] firstRow, ref string[] secondRow)
    {
        // StopWatch tests suggest TextFieldParser appears to be marginally faster than a StreamReader
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(file.Path))
        {
            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
            if (file.TextDelimiter == "\"")
            {
                parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            }

            if (file.FieldDelimiter == null)
            {
                file.FieldDelimiter = ParseFirstRow(parser.ReadLine(), ref firstRow);
                parser.Delimiters = new string[] { file.FieldDelimiter };
            }
            else
            {
                parser.Delimiters = new string[] { file.FieldDelimiter };
                firstRow = parser.ReadFields();
            }

            secondRow = parser.ReadFields();
        }
    }

    public string ParseFirstRow(string firstLine, ref string[] firstRow)
    {
        firstLine = firstLine.Trim('\"', '\'');
        if (firstLine.Contains('|'))
        {
            firstRow = Regex.Split(firstLine, "[\"']*\\|[\"']*");
            return "|";
        }
        else if (firstLine.Contains(','))
        {
            firstRow = Regex.Split(firstLine, "[\"']*,[\"']*");
            return ",";
        }
        else if (firstLine.Contains('\t'))
        {
            firstRow = Regex.Split(firstLine, "[\"']*\t[\"']*");
            return "\t";
        }

        firstRow = Regex.Split(firstLine, "[\"']*[:;@#~\\.&_\t,-]*[\"']*");
        return "";
    }

    public bool IsFileDoubleQuoteDelimited(string[] lineText)
    {
        string line = string.Join(" ", lineText);
        int countOfChar = line.Length - line.Replace("\"", "").Length
        if (countOfChar == (lineText.Count() * 2))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this how your code is organised in the real thing or have you moved it all to the controller to make it easier to post?

Comment: @RobH I've moved it to make it easier to post. In the real code the Controller has the NewJob function and all the other functions are in a separate FileParser class which is injected into the controller.

Comment: @MattThrower You shouldn't do that, because "you should split those methods into separate classes" is a valid review, but it's not applicable to your real code.

Comment: @svick Fair enough. I have classed the code as requested. I'd dearly love to put a bounty on this, as it seems a great learning opportunity, but I can't afford it :(

Answer (score 1):

Its a little bit hard to follow the `ActionResult NewJob(Job job)` method but this can be fixed by using a guard condition like so

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid || Request.Files.Count == 0)
{
    return View("Error");
}

HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
if (file == null || file.ContentLength == 0)
{
    return View("Error");
}  

// the remaining code
```

but this will still have some small code duplication. So why don't we add a method using the `TryGet` pattern like so

```
private bool TryGetFile(out HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    file = null;
    if (!ModelState.IsValid || Request.Files.Count == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    file = Request.Files[0];
    return file != null && file.ContentLength > 0;
}
```

and use it like so

```
HttpPostedFileBase file;
if (!TryGetFile(out file))
{
    return View("Error");
}
```

---

You really have to work on naming things. Let us stay at the `NewJob()` method.

- methods should be named using a verb or verb phrase.
- don't use abbreviations for naming things. Abbreviations will lead to code which is hard to read and to maintain.
- if you are dealing with a collection you should use the plural form of the name. See: `string[] firstline = null;`.
- declaring multiple variables on the same line reduces the readability